# Isolation Scheduler in Apache Storm

Tags: stream, apache-storm, isolation

I have defined two topology and use Isolation Scheduler in Nimbus. I have allocated below configuration to my topology.

```
isolation.scheduler.machines:
 "Topology-Test1": 2
 "Topology-Test2": 3
```

Now , I want if there is no work coming for `Topology-Test2`. Then, all 3 nodes will be assigned to `Topology-Test1`. But when traffic comes for `Topology-Test2`. Then, all 3 nodes should be reassigned to `Topology-Test2`.

is it possible in Storm to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

While a straight forward implementation is not supported by Storm directly imho, there are two pointers here that might help you:

1. **[T-3 Scheduler](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167739X17326432?via%3Dihub)**: *In this paper, we propose a heuristic scheduling algorithm – T3-Scheduler – for a heterogeneous fog or cloud cluster that can efficiently identify the tasks that communicate with each other and assign them to the same node, up to a specified level of utilisation for that node.*
2. **[Resource Aware Scheduler](https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.1.0/Resource_Aware_Scheduler_overview.html)**: Maybe you can hijack that somehow. According to the docs: *Resource Aware Scheduler can allocate resources on a per user basis. Each user can be guaranteed a certain amount of resources to run his or her topologies and the Resource Aware Scheduler will meet those guarantees when possible. When the Storm cluster has extra free resources, Resource Aware Scheduler will to be able allocate additional resources to user in a fair manner. The importance of topologies can also vary. Topologies can be used for actual production or just experimentation, thus Resource Aware Scheduler will take into account the importance of a topology when determining the order in which to schedule topologies or when to evict topologies*

Good luck with finding your strategy.